# Is a Hollowtech II BB compatible with an Octalink Crank? (Shimano Claris)

Tags: road-bike, crankset, bottom-bracket, compatibility

If I fit a Shimano Hollowtech II Bottom Bracket (Claris), can I still use my Octalink Claris crank?

Comment: Good news is the price of a new, Claris-level Octalink bottom bracket is a few dollars less than an HT2. The selection of the correct Octalink BB of several choices within the same model number can be tricky, but the specific crankset and a couple parameters of the bike provide the info to select the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot, they are fundamentally different. Octalink uses a 3-piece crankset and Hollowtech 2 uses a 2-pice crankset.

The 3-piece means that the spindle is integrated in the Octalink BB. The 2-piece means that the spindle is integrated with the right crank and inserted through the hollow BB.

The BB is usually much cheaper than the crank so it is normal to buy the BB you need for your crankset if the crankset is OK. One only buys a different BB if their new crankset requires it.